# How to DROP DATABASE named "/"

Tags: mysql, database, syntax, drop-database

There is this database created automatically with a CMS. the database name is "/" without quotes. and when trying do delete it, this shows up.

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE /; 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/' at line 1
```

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.24, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try enclosing the slash in single backticks.

Comment: You are welcome. Those backticks are generelly useful when working with mysql, also when dealing with fancy table names like `time` or the like...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need backticks:

```
DROP DATABASE `/`;
```

Comment: Sorry, but those are _not_ single quotes.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what it is called in english ;-)

Comment: Just look in the comments below the question.